# Conditions and files

Tags: c++, file, input

```
class Client
{
    public:
    Client(int id, string title, int age):
    ~Client();
    void addTW(int id, string title, int age);
    int getID() const {return id;}
    string getTitle() const {return title;}
    int getAge() const {return age;}
    private:
    int id; 
    string title;
    int age;
 };
```

I have two functions:

`load()`, which is loading input `.txt` file - file's having titles of movies and age you need to have in order to watch the movie (e.x. Pulp Fiction - 16) and

`addTW(int id, string title, int age)`, which adds Movies.

So, while adding a movie, you need to type id, title and age. I want to make that you cannot add movie if you're under a certain age (e.x. 16 or whatever). Age must be re-added from the `.txt` file. Basically age in connected with and only title.

I've never used `.txt` files. So I have no idea how to start.

---

```
    #include <fstream>
void Client::addTW(int id, string title, int age)
{
   int i, n = tw.size();
   for(i = 0;i<n;i++)
   {
      ToWatch* newTW = new ToWatch(id, title, age);
      tw.push_back(newTW);
      return;
   }
}
```

---

```
void Client::load()
{
   ifstream input;
   input.open("input.txt");
   if(input.fail())
   { cout<<"Failure"<<endl;}
   else
   {
       string s;
       while(input>>s)
       {
           cout<<s<<" ";
       }
   }
   input.close();
}
```

Comment: What is your question? I am happy to help, but which question should I answer? You need to give more details. And, if you have a class, like Client, you need to show the definition. Otherwise no help possible.

Comment: When adding a new movie, I want the funcition  to check if movie's title has been written in the file - If so, it should read age assigned to the movie. If you add movie having 15 year, but the movie is from 16 there should be warning or sth like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure, if the design of your class is OK. This you can find out by yourself.

I can help you with reading the file and extracting the age for a given title:

Please see:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

unsigned int getAgeFromFile(const std::string& title) {

    // We set a default age of 0. So, if we cannot find the title in the list, then everybody can look it
    unsigned int resultingAge{ 0 };

    // Define an ifstream variable. Use its constructor, to open the file, then check, if open was ok
    if (std::ifstream fileMovies("input.txt"); fileMovies) {

        // Read all lines in the text file in a loop with std::getline. std::getline will return false,
        // if we are at end-of-file or in case of some other error. Then the loop will stop
        for (std::string line{}; std::getline(fileMovies, line); ) {

            // So, now we have a line from the file in tour "line" variable.
            // Check, if the searched title is in it
            if (line.find(title) != std::string::npos) {

                // Ok, we found the title in this line. Now, we need to extract the age.
                // It is at the end of the line and separated by a space. So, search from the end of the line for a space
                if (size_t pos{ line.rfind(' ') }; pos != std::string::npos) {
                    // We found a space. Now, convert the number.
                    resultingAge = std::stoul(line.substr(pos));
                }
            }
        }
    }
    // return result or default value, if not found
    return resultingAge;
}
```

In your `addTW` function you need to insert one line before the 
`push_back`.

```
if (age > getAgeFromFile(title))
```

Hope this helps.

Compiled and tested with VS2019 and C++17